# How do I format a query to fetch an aggregate root with just related ids

Tags: npoco

Let's say I have the following object in my domain.

```
    [TableName("work_space")]
    public class WorkSpace
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Column(Name="owner_id")]
        public long OwnerId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<int> OrgIds { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<int> SettingIds { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<int> UserIds { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<long> WorkViewIds { get; set; }
    }
```

This is one way to fetch the data that I need.

```
SELECT ws.*, wsu.user_id as UserId, wss.setting_id as SettingId, wso.org_id as OrgId, wv.id as WorkViewId
FROM work_space ws
LEFT OUTER JOIN work_space_user wsu ON ws.id = wsu.work_space_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN work_space_setting wss ON ws.id = wss.work_space_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN work_space_org wso ON ws.id = wso.work_space_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN work_view wv ON ws.id = wv.work_space_id
WHERE ws.id = @0
```

How is this usually done in NPoco?  Would I use a multi Result set fetch? Some sort of Fetch one to Many?  Do I flag my ID collections as Result or Ignore Columns?  I'm just not finding any examples like this in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most intuitive way to do this I have found to do this so far.  It works ok for a single entity, but when I want to fetch collections of them, I'm having n+1 problems as go back to the database for each object in the collection to fetch the relations.

```
    public WorkSpace GetWorkSpace(int id)
    {
        using (Database db = DbFactory.VSurveyDbFactory.GetDatabase())
        {
            WorkSpace workspace = db.SingleById<WorkSpace>(id);

            StringBuilder sqlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sqlBuilder.Append(@"SELECT * FROM work_space_user WHERE work_space_id = @0;");
            sqlBuilder.Append(@"SELECT * FROM work_space_setting WHERE work_space_id = @0;");
            sqlBuilder.Append(@"SELECT * FROM work_space_org WHERE work_space_id = @0;");
            sqlBuilder.Append(@"SELECT * FROM work_view WHERE work_space_id = @0;");

            Tuple<List<int>, List<int>, List<int>, List<long>> results = db.FetchMultiple<int, int, int, long>(sqlBuilder.ToString(), id);

            workspace.UserIds = results.Item1;
            workspace.SettingIds = results.Item2;
            workspace.OrgIds = results.Item3;
            workspace.WorkViewIds = results.Item4;

            return workspace;
        }
    }
```